# How to avoid displaying "&quot;" instead of quote marks?

Tags: html, unicode

I have a PC running Windows 7. Surfing the web, I see plenty of normal quotation marks (", ') around. But occasionally, I'll see it written out as its HTML entity like this: `&quot;`. I frequently see it on well-designed, big budget websites whose designers should know what they're doing, like IGN or CNN.

I'm curious as to why I'm seeing this, and if there's something wrong with my browser or computer. But my real question is this: is there a way to prevent special characters from appearing as HTML entities when other people, especially with older systems, view *my* website?

**Generally speaking, what kind of code could cause this problem to arise, and how can it be prevented?**

Comment: its malformed webpage and nothing to do with your computer.  The owner of the website needs to fix it.

Comment: @Sorceri Do you know specifically what coding errors can cause it?

Comment: These are not Unicode, they are HTML entities that shouldn't show up, as Sorceri says. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: `Do you know specifically what coding errors can cause it?` double-encoded HTML can cause it (like when there is a `&quot;` that would show up as a `"` but then gets encoded *again* so the literal `&quot;` shows up on the page. There is likely nothing for you to worry about on your own web site

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that they were using JQuery's `text()` function instead of the `html()` function. That would cause the `&quot;` to be shown rather than an actual quotation mark. The reason for this is because `text()` adds escape characters so that whatever is passed into it will be shown exactly the same when view on a web page (see below).

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), [which] does not interpret the string as HTML.
>   (Source: http://api.jquery.com/text)

The escape character `&amp` is probably what was added to the front of `quot;` by `text()` which would cause it to be displayed as `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the web developer literally typed `&quot;` and the HTML editor made it `&amp;quot;`. You may check the page source.

Answer (score 0):

```
     .replace(/&quot;|&#039;/g, "'")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck